# Flask-JWT-Extended set cookies with double submit cookie method, prevent HTTP-only cookie

Tags: nginx, cookies, httponly, flask-jwt-extended

I'm using Flask-JWT-Extended and double submit cookie method from there for my Flask backend and React Frontend. So when user logs in from frontend, backend sets total of 4 different cookeis: `csrf_access_token`, `csrf_refresh_token`, `access_token_cookie`, `refresh_token_cookie`. Out of these 4 cookies, `access_token_cookie` and `refresh_token_cookie` should be `HTTPonly` cookie, and thus not accessible by JS and `csrf_access_token` and `csrf_refresh_token` are `non-HTTPonly` cookie. So the idea here is that `HTTPOnly` cookie holds user's session information with CSRF token and `non-HTTPonly` cookie holds the CSRF token and when POST request is made, CSRF token accessed by JS is sent to backend along with the other cookies.

This was working just fine in my development environment, two of the cookies were accessible by JavaScript and thus I could send `csrf_acccess_token` along with the request with `withCredentials` True, but when I deploy this to test environment with TLS using Nginx (Both backend and frontend), it is setting all 4 cookies as `HTTPOnly` cookie, and thus, I cannot make any POST request.

I'm not sure whether this was caused by the `Nginx`, but from what I can tell, I don't see much options to turn off 2 of the `HTTPOnly` cookies being registered from the backend.

Below is my configuration for `flask-jwt-extended`

```
CORS_HEADERS = "Content-Type,X-CSRF-TOKEN"
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ["cookies"]
JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = True
#JWT_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES = 600
JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES = 1200
JWT_CSRF_IN_COOKIES = True
JWT_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mydomain.com"
#JWT_ACCESS_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
#JWT_REFRESH_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
JWT_SECRET_KEY = "secret"
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-JWT-Extended should never be setting the csrf cookies as httponly. I wonder if there is an nginx setting that is converting all cookies to httponly (something like proxy_cookie_path)?

If that’s the case, another approach you could take it to set `JWT_CSRF_IN_COOKIES` to false, and use https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#flask_jwt_extended.get_csrf_token to grab the csrf token when a JWT is created, return it as part of the JSON payload, and store it in localStorage instead of in those non-httponly cookies so that your JavaScript can still grab it when making requests.

Comment: It turns out that, apache running on the backend server had a confi where it changed all cookies to http only. Thanks!